# Private fields and encapsulation

Tags: c#, encapsulation

I'm reading the head first c# book and don't quite understand what this means.
"Any class can see private fields in another instances of the same class"

Answer (score 4):

Consider these classes:

```
class A
{
    private int foo;

    public A(int f) { this.foo = f; }

    // works
    public int AddTo(A other) { return this.foo + other.foo; }

    // doesn't work: 'B.bar' is inaccessible due to its protection level
    public int AddTo(B other) { return this.foo + other.bar; }
}    

class B
{
    public B(int b) { this.bar = b; }

    private int bar;
}

var a1 = new A(123);
var a2 = new A(456);

var result = a1.AddTo(a2);
```

Here, the `a1` instance of `A` accesses `a2`'s private `foo` value. result will be 579.

However, the second method, `AddTo(B)` doesn't work -- it won't even compile -- because `A` instances don't have access to `B` instances private members.

```
var b = new B(789);
var result2 = a1.Add2(b);
```

Here, `a1` tries to access `b`'s private `bar` member, but because `a1` is an instance of `A` and `b` is an instance of `B`, the latter's private `bar` member is inaccessible.

Comment: I would separate that code block into two examples, to show the one that works vs. the one that doesn't. I was a little confused at first reading this.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: BTW, this has an interesting and very important consequence: the defining difference between objects and Abstract Data Types is that objects cannot see each other's privates, whereas ADT instances can see privates of other instances of the same type. Since instances of the same class *can* see each other's privates, they aren't objects, they are ADT instances. OTOH, instances of the same interface can *not* see each other's privates and are thus objects. So, in C♯, classes define ADTs, not objects, interfaces define objects. IOW: it's not classes that make C♯ object-oriented, it's interfaces.

Comment: And a program that uses classes as types (i.e. use a class (or struct) as the type of a local variable, field, property, method return type, method parameter, generic type argument, cast operator, `as` operator, `instanceof` operator, `is` operator, delegate type, etc.) is not object-oriented. Only interfaces can be used as types, classes/structs can only be used as factories, i.e. a class/struct name can only appear directly after the `new` operator. Note: there's nothing wrong with writing and/or using ADTs in C♯, but if you *want* to write OO, you have to follow these rules.

Answer (score 0):

If class `Foo` has a private member, such as

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _bar;
}
```

Then `_bar` is accessible from within any instance of `Foo`.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _bar;

    public bool MatchesOtherFoo(Foo other)
    {
        return _bar == other._bar;
    }
}
```

You couldn't access `_bar` from another class, but you can access it from other instances of the same class.